# Facebook Android SDK: 'cannot resolve symbol EVENT_NAME_SUBSCRIBE'

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to implement the following Facebook SDK standard event :

```
/**
 * This function assumes logger is an instance of AppEventsLogger and has been
 * created using AppEventsLogger.newLogger() call.
 */
public void logSubscribeEvent (String orderId, String currency, double price) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_ORDER_ID, orderId);
    params.putString(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_PARAM_CURRENCY, currency);
    logger.logEvent(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_SUBSCRIBE, price, params);
}
```

defined [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android/).

But I get the following errors:

- Cannot resolve symbol EVENT_PARAM_ORDER_ID
- Cannot resolve symbol EVENT_NAME_SUBSCRIBE

I see no possibility to import a Facebook lib to solve this issue.

Any solution?

Thanks !

Comment: Where do you get orderId from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your gradle file

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
```